# wicked_pdf: ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, sprockets, wicked-pdf

We have some PDF generation code working fine in the dev environment, but Rails is showing an error when we try to render it on production:

```
***************WICKED***************
  Rendered invoices/show.pdf.haml within layouts/invoices_pdf.pdf (8.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 73ms

ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
```

It fails trying to include the application.css asset in:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{"http-equiv"=>"content-type", :content=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
    = wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application"

  %body
    .container
      = yield
```

Comment: Can you post your application.css file and your CSS file hierarchy (app/assets, vendor/assets, and lib/assets)?

Comment: @okeen - did you try out my answer?

Answer (score 3):

The css file 'twitter/bootstrap.css' will likely not exist in production, as sprockets will compile it into application.css - this will not be the case in development, however, where sprockets maintains separate files by default.

Are you referencing twitter/bootstrap.css specifically in your code? If so, changing the reference to application.css for production will likely solve the issue.

Comment: Hey, I also suspect this is some asset-pipeline issue, but no, we are referencing the application.css file:  wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application". Although this method is wicked_pdf's exclusive, changing it to a regular stylesheet_link_tag doesn't help either. Thanks.

Comment: how have you installed bootstrap? Did you use a gem?

Comment: @newton, yeap gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the less-rails-bootstrap under the `:asset` group in your gemfile? If so, move it out from there, and it might do the job!

Comment: well, this didn't solve the problem but at least now I have a different error: RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
"/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q . I'll investigate further on this. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I didn't find the solution because of lack of time, but I will give you the bounty because you were the one who at least showed me where to go... thx!